# Get partial r from multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I have a question related to multiple regression in R.

1. How to get r (not R squared) from multiple regression. I think do square root of R squared is not the answer, because r may be a negative number. For linear regression, I know that I can run *cor* (correlation) to calculate r value, but how can I do it in multiple regression?
2. How can I get partial r (i.e, to see how each independent variable contribute to the final prediction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know, it is impossible to calculate r from multiple
   regression as the formulas are different. If you want r, just
   calculate the correlation. If you want a correlation that is
   corrected for other independent variables (the way that regression
   also corrects), you want the partial r that you requested in your
   next question.
2. There are multiple functions for partial correlations. For example, the `pcor()` function from the `ggm` package, or the `pcor()` function from the `ppcor` package.

Comment: I tried with ``pcor`` from package ``ppcor``, and when I run ``pcor.test(x1,x2,y)`` it gives me only one correlation (in **esimate** column). I do not understand well: I suppose that it should be 2 values, one for x1 and one for x2, similar with ``cor (x1, y)``. Am I wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `pcor.test()` function gives you the partial correlation between x1 and x2, corrected for their correlations with y. So you would get one partial correlation.

Comment: What the method is used in `pcor` from `ggm` package, _Spearman_ or _Pearson_?

Comment: You can request the method, `pcor` has the options for Spearman, Pearson, and Kendall. See the `method` parameter when you look at the help section of the function.